# How can I call python function from html on button click and display the result returned by function

Tags: python, html, node.js, onclick

This is my simple html code index.html

```
    <html>
           <head>
               <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
           </head>
           <body>
               <input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="alert">
           </body>
      </html>
```

this is index.js file

```
       fun(){}
           const spawn=require('child_process').spawn;
           const process=spawn('python',['./hello.py']);
           process.stdout.on('data',(data)=>{
               console.log(data.toString());
           })
       }
```

this is hello.py file

```
print("Hello world")
```

I have tried this ,but on button click this is giving me error about require..
Any suggestions how can I do this.??

Comment: Can you provide the exact error?

Comment: Uncaught reference error: require is not defined -this the error displayed on console

Comment: Browsers don't have the require method defined, but Node.js does. With Browserify you can write code that uses require in the same way that you would use it in Node.

http://browserify.org/

And it cannot spawn `python`